# Size of End-User Database Application Market (Microsoft Access, Filemaker Pro, etc.)

Tags: database

This is not a technical question, but thought I'd throw it out anyway.

I am in need of a rough size of the End-User Database Application market.  Specifically, I'm talking about products like Microsoft Access and Filemaker Pro.

Does anyone know where I could find such information (preferably without paying $5000 for a market research report...)?

Answer (score 1):

microsoft annual report should talk about ms access, and have info about market size, penetration, forcase, etc.

Comment: Been there.  It's numbers don't go into detail of Access vs. the rest of Office.